# 3D? No-no! 3 Sides

Tags: visual, geometry, grid-deduction, nonogram, triangle

### Introducing the Isometric Nonogram!

**α) "Boar"ing Definition** <sub>*[oink]*</sub>

> [image]
>   **Column**: Blue Part + Green Cell
>   **Row**: Yellow Part + Green Cell
>   **Adjacent/ Continuous cells**: Purple Cell + **any** of the Orange Cells

**β) Clues**

> [image]
>
> - All clues are provided.
> - Only one colour, **red** is needed for this nonogram.
> - All clues are either from the left to the right or from the top to the bottom
> - Clues along the blue edges are column clues, and those along the scarlet edges are row clues

I apologise for messiness of the clues, so here is how you read them: Each clue is denoted by one colour. It is, I believe and I hope, not hard to interpret.

> [image]

**γ) The Puzzle**

> [image]

**ω) Postscript**

Thanks for all your enthusiastic participation. I must apologise for forgetting to note beforehand that the objective of this nonogram, and many of my others, is to interpret the nonogram and get a message. Sorry!

Have fun!

Comment: At the left corner, I think there's a conflict; the leftmost row clue is "1 1 1 2 1 4", however there are two adjacent column clues, "1" and "3", where each one fills the column it's on. This results in the middle row having at least 2 red tiles at the start, while it's only supposed to have 1.

Comment: @EKons the clue to the middle row is on the right: "2 1 1 2 3 2". the nonogram is fine. thanks for asking!

Comment: Oh, the clues were a little confusing.

Comment: This puzzle's solution is really awesome! +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [image]

I was trying to post this 5 minutes before the other answer, but got snookered by camp wifi

> the puzzle appears to read "RUBIO"

Comment: it was a pity that you were sniped due the sad wifi... but still i have to give u_ndefined the check due to the timestamp. were you the sniper against the unfortunate answerer, i would still have given you the check. upvoted, keep up your great work, and happy puzzling!

Comment: but they did not solve it fully, they ignored the hidden message

Answer (score 8):

Here is the solution to the puzzle (note the correction in "3,1,2,5" to "3,1,2,1,4", by comment [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86308/3d-no-no-3-sides/86322#comment251025_86308)):

> [image: solution]

Comment: well done, check here!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I have upvoted u_ndefined for solving the nonogram as presented and downvoted your question for assuming an "easter egg" is somehow more important than the puzzle was.

Comment: u_ndefined, i am so sorry to remove your check, but then micsthepick reminded me that the aim is to find the meaning of the nonogram. sorry for not stating this explicitly.

Comment: @DarkThunder thanks so much for your feedback. i appreciate this a lot!